# Set any application's volume

Tags: c#, .net, pinvoke, audio

I was wondering how I could set a specific application (as in any running application, not just my own)'s volume level in c#.

I know I'd probably have to use P/invoke, this is fine. I'm just not sure on how the sound api's work and how I would go about getting/setting the volume of specific applications (like the volume mixer in vista/7 can).

I know it's possible to do programattically because [nircmd has a feature](http://nircmd.nirsoft.net/setappvolume.html) that can do it.

Any help would be appriciated, thanks.

Comment: From a post in the first google hit: http://www.geekpedia.com/tutorial176_Get-and-set-the-wave-sound-volume.html

Comment: @MrFox - unfortunately the code at that link just describes how to change the global WaveOut volume. The OP is looking for separate control over individual applications' settings.

Comment: This is enabled by WASAPI, a new audio api available for Vista and up.  It is a COM api of a kind that's particularly unfriendly to C# since it isn't automation compatible.  Find wrappers written by others by googling +c# +wasapi

Comment: Windows vista really allows one app to reset another's volume?   That seems like a huge opportunity for really annoying apps to exploit.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb945061.aspx). Following the links you'll find interfaces and API functions to use to manipulate endpoints' volume. Together with the documentation, Microsoft provided some code samples in C++. As you said, it is possible to get the same functionalities to work in .NET using platform invoke.

Answer (score -8):

I think (and hope) your request is, for all intents and purposes, impossible. Allowing an application to set its own volume is like allowing an application to override the user's notification icon settings. These settings are user settings, so you can't circumvent them.

Imagine for an instance that a user has the volume of his speakers set way up, but has dimmed the volumes of all individual applications. Your application comes along and goes 'whatevs, I'll just set myself to full volume'. You've just made a user go deaf, or at least cower in a corner of the room, scared to death.

Comment: -1. There are perfectly valid reasons to do this and it might be the main purpose of an application in which case the user would expect this.